# How to call a function in a custom control from a form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Please consider the following Windows Forms code:

```
namespace SameWinFormsProject
{
    // Top-level form.

    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); // Boilerplate code.
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle local;

            local = GetButtonFace(); // error CS0103: The name 'GetButtonFace' does not exist in the current context
        }
    }

    // Custom button control.

    class MyCustomButton: Button
    {
        Rectangle face;

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // ...
        }

        Rectangle GetButtonFace()
        {
            return face;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call the `GetButtonFace()` function (which belongs to the `MyCustomButton` class) from anywhere in the top level form `Form1`?

Comment: You need an instance of `MyCustomButton` in your Form class, also your class `MyCustomButton`'s method `GetButtonFace` should have return type

Comment: @Habib: `GetButtonFace()` has return type `Rectangle`

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi, lol yes :) need to format the code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a member's visibility is `private` by default.

Second, is the `face` rectangle supposed to be available without an instance of `MyCustomButton`? If so then make it static:

```
internal static GetButtonFace()
{
    return face;
}
```

Of course `face` would also have to be static:

```
static Rectangle face;
```

If a static method is not what you want then you need an instance of `MyCustomButton` to call your method on, as Sudhakar suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You need an instance variable to access the `GetButtonFace()` method as it is in another class.

Try This:

```
MyCustomButton mybutton=new MyCustomButton();
local = mybutton.GetButtonFace();
```

Comment: To add for the OP, the instance variable probably already exists if you are using the Forms Designer in Visual Studio.  It will be the `(Name)` property when you select the button.  You can use that as your instance variable from anywhere within your form.

Comment: @selkathguy +1 Yes, the instance already exists, and that was what I was missing.  Thank you.

Comment: @selkathguy  Since your comment was critical in answering my question, I have voted for your other answers to make sure you receive credit.